# No data recorded in Experience Analytics

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

We have made a installation of Sitecore Experience Platform v9.3.0 (rev. 003498) (details below):

- 2 servers as Content Management role
- 2 servers as Content Delivery role
- 2 servers as others roles (Processing, Reporting, Identity Server, XConnect, Identity Server, Marketing, Reference Data, Cortex)
- 3 servers as Solr

The application has been running for approximately 45 days, however, Experience Analytics and Experience Profile are not recording data (no data is displayed). we have checked the logs of all roles and found no errors that could help us fix the issue.

After some research we have changed the **"IndexAnonymousContactData"** tag to **true** in the **"{XCONNECT_PATH}\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\config\sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings"** configuration file and rebuilt the indexes. However, it did not work.

Would anyone have any suggestions on what we could do to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Seems like can find solution here  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/experience-analytics-are-not-showing-online-interactions

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for analytics data not showing, there is a knowledge base article describes the processes for troubleshooting the most frequent issues with Analytics data in the Sitecore Experience Database installation, I would suggest to go through and troubleshoot:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similer issue in my local instance. I have gone with the [Knowledge base article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) and some other blogs as well and tried multiple solutions.

There are possible fixed provide in below article you can try that one:

[Display Anonymous Contacts in Sitecore Experience Profile](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/showing-anonymous-contacts-in-sitecore.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to head about EE not showing any data, Specially with this issue, there are n no. of issues which are possible but some quick pointers

1. Do you see any error on screen in RED, when you open experience profile?, or if you open firebug and go to console tab and hit refresh do you see any errors?
2. Is xDB enabled? you can find that from config and also from sitecore logs

I have had this nightmarish situation where i was not able to get my head around why it is not working, But if you observed the log closely there might be some exceptions which might help

3. Can you see in DB interactions are there? if they are there meaning only processing and aggregation is not happening, so you can narrow down your research to processing and reporting roles

http://daivagnananavati.blogspot.com/2019/06/experience-analytics-not-working.html

I have registered some of my findings here, see if those are helpful to you, else we can talk more on it, but i would strongly advise to check if certificates are fine and you are able to hit all those processing and reporting urls without an issue